# How to get rid of password security warnings in Firebug?

Tags: html, firefox-addon, firebug

I'm working on websites, which don't have SSL enabled, but every time I open Firebug's *Console* panel, it shows errors related to SSL:

> Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a
> security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.
>
> Password fields present in a form with an insecure (http://) form
> action. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to
> be stolen.
>
> Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This
> is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.
>
> Password fields present in a form with an insecure (http://) form
> action. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to
> be stolen.

How to disable such warnings? I.e. how to set Firebug not to show them?

Comment: @Quentin: I'm not the site owner, so I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug currently (version 2.0.x) doesn't allow to filter specific console messages permanently. This feature is requested in [issue 4368](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4368).

As upcoming Firebug versions are based on the built-in DevTools, [bug 837774](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=837774) asking to add an API to the DevTools to allow custom filtering, may also be relevant.

*Note that these error messages actually come from Firefox itself, Firebug just displays them.*